# Is there any way in C# to automatically set the DefaultValueAttribute for properties that have default values set?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to implicitly carry out the following pattern?

```
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool SomeBooleanProperty { get; set; } = true;
```

Repeating the default value in two locations just seems to be begging for mistakes somewhere and in any case seems very redundant. I can imagine some cases where having the DefaultValueAttribute automatically set to the default value (or any value) would be undesirable, but I think those would be the exception rather than the rule. And in those cases the solution would simply be to set the default value in the constructor rather than at declaration which I think is less burdensome than redundant code.

Comment: AFAIK, The DefaultValue attribute is only there to tell the property grid what's the default value of the property. It has no effect of the actual default value. However, this is a good question. +1.

Comment: It is nothing that a `private const` can't solve.  That such a const has to be used twice can be intuitively obvious if you think a bit about how the designer can know what the default might be *before* executing any of the code you wrote.  Just inverting the logic so that `false` is the default is another way to get ahead.

Comment: well i would suggest that you just invert the logic, so that the default is false. ill try with an example. if the property name was 'Enabled' then its always off by default but if you change its name to 'Disabled'  then its always on by default. Maybe my example is not the best but you get the idea, change the wording so that the default of false is correct.

Comment: One of workarounds - you can write f.e. Fody Weaver, it will do it for you at.. compile time: http://intellitect.com/creating-fody-addin/

Comment: Hans, I also thought about this path I mean at that point you've solved the problem of danger, but now have 3 lines of code just to declare an auto property.

Comment: Zohar, the DefaultValueAttribute is used to determine whether or not the designer auto-sets values for properties. A mismatch between the desired default value and the DefaultValueAttribute default value can result in objects being improperly initialized and lead to otherwise unexpected behavior - especially as types are updated over time. E.g. if you don't specify a DefaultValueAttribute and change the default value for a bool from false to true, then all older instances of that object from the designer will still be using false even if the user actually wanted the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN says this about the [DefaultValueAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically
>   initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value
>   in your code.

[This](http://www.barsoom.org/defaultvalue-attribute-initial) article suggests doing something like this to avoid repeated code

```
static public void ApplyDefaultValues(object self)
{
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(self)) {
        DefaultValueAttribute attr = prop.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)] as DefaultValueAttribute;
        if (attr == null) continue;
        prop.SetValue(self, attr.Value);
    }
}
```